# $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}( \cos{\sqrt{n+1}} - \cos{\sqrt{n}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please, help me with this sequence... I am working really hard on sequences, and I struggle... Please, explain. You will have my up vote and eternal gratitude.

Comment: Hint: $\cos(\sqrt{n+1})-\cos(\sqrt{n})=2\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{1+n}}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{1+n}}{2}\right)$

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply kind Sir, but I don't know what to do next...

Comment: $\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{1+n}}{2}\right)$ is bounded. You need to show  that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{1+n}}{2}\right)=0$. ;)

Comment: Thank you! I get that it's bounded, because of the range of sine function, bounds are [-1,1]. Why does it have to be zero?

Comment: I correct a typo. You need to show that $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{1+n}}{2}\right)=0$$ so you can use the squeeze theorem

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is this OK? 

0 <= ![\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}] <= ![{n}/{2^{n}}]

And please, please... Can you give me a good page to learn how to write math expressions, the easy to read way. Thank you for your time!

To prove that lim n/(2^n) = 0 I used the Stolz theorem, but to be frank, I am not really sure if  (sqrt(n+1) - sqrt(n))*1/2 <=n/(2^n).

Comment: To write the formulas you have to use latex formula between two dollars simbols. To solve the limit just multiply and divide by $\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{1+n}$ so you get $$\\ \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{1+n}}{2}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{1+n})\cdot (\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{1+n})}{2\cdot(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{1+n})}\right)=\\ \\ \\ =\sin\left(\frac{n-1-n}{2(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{1+n})}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{-1}{2(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{1+n})}\right)$$ so $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sin\left(\frac{-1}{2(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{1+n})}\right)=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way of solving would be to "convert" to real numbers and use the Mean Value Theorem. Let $f(x) = \cos(\sqrt{x})$, which is obviously differentiable. Then we have by MVT that $\exists c \in (x,x+1)$ s.t.

$$\frac{\cos(\sqrt{x+1}) - \cos(\sqrt{x})}{x+1-x} = f'(c) = - \frac{\sin(\sqrt{c})}{2\sqrt{c}}$$

Now taking limit $x \to \infty$ from both sides (this gives us $c \to \infty$):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos(\sqrt{x+1}) - \cos(\sqrt{x}) = \lim_{c \to \infty} - \frac{\sin(\sqrt{c})}{2\sqrt{c}} = 0$$

Now as the limit exists for real numbers it must hold for natural numbers too.

Comment: Nice solution +1

Comment: Wow. Awesome! Never thought of it that way. 

Can you please be kind enough to explain to me how you got -sin(sqrt(x))/(2*sqrt(c)) ?

Comment: @Shocky2 Chain Rule

Comment: Thanks! But what do you mean by "Now taking limit ${x \to \infty}$ from both sides" ? Can you please explain it a bit more in detail?

Comment: @Shocky2 I don't know how to make it more simple. I mean we get a relation from the MVT and then we look what happens when x is approaching infinity. If it makes it more simple for you you can just substitute what we got from the equation into the initial statement from the problem

Comment: @Stefan4024 You are right. Thanks a lot. You are a great helper!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: use that $$\cos(x)-\cos(y)=-2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right) \sin
   \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply kind Sir, but I don't know what to do next...

Comment: ... You might want to start by setting $x = \sqrt{n+1}$, $y = \sqrt n$

Comment: I get that.... But after I transform the expression, what then?